# python package-dependency charts.... finding what fixes a version of a library

Tags: python, conda

I've a conda install that's giving me an install of `pysal` back on version 2.1.0 (it's currently 2.5.0) ... and I'm trying to figure out which of the 73 already installed packages has specified such an old version.

I know [pydeps](https://github.com/thebjorn/pydeps) will find me the dependencies for a given package... all the packages required to run `foo` - but I want to go the other way: what packages need `foo` to be present (and the version they ask for would be nice.)

(I've got as far as recognising it's probably going to involve hunting through the json files in `conda-meta`)

Answer (score 1):

you can use pipdeptree:

```
pip install pipdeptree
pipdeptree
```

and get the dependencies in a tree form, like:

```
flake8==2.5.0
  - mccabe [required: >=0.2.1,<0.4, installed: 0.3.1]
  - pep8 [required: !=1.6.0,>=1.5.7,!=1.6.1,!=1.6.2, installed: 1.5.7]
  - pyflakes [required: >=0.8.1,<1.1, installed: 1.0.0]
ipdb==0.8
  - ipython [required: >=0.10, installed: 1.1.0]
```

one of the packages has installed this version but probably, it does not depend on this specific version, so you can also try to just install the most recent version and test if it works.
Test and figure out dependencies is one of the reasons why we use virtual environments (like conda) so don't be afraid of break everything, if it happens, just save the env:

```
conda env export > your_env_name.yml
```

create the virtualenv again:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

or just clone your current env to another before change it:

```
conda create --name current_env_name --clone backup_env
```

Comment: Thanks for this... pipdeptree does what I want.... especially with the `--reverse` option!

Sadly, it doesn't actually show me anything that's specifying the dependency.

[For full disclosure: this is a conda install, in a docker image.... and I can pin-point a Dockfile change 2 months ago, however I have no docker images available from before that to actually pip-point when the change happened in practice, so see what else changed to impact that.]

.... but this is definitely a solid answer!